# What is the probability of a 3 digit code that is randomly chosen will be 633

Tags: probability

What is the probability of a 3 digit code that is randomly chosen will be 633?

My question is pretty straight forward so hopefully, there are no problems

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Questions are generally better received if you add more context to the problem and explain what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This would be 1 out of all possible 3 digit numbers. 1/(900) = .001111

(assuming you cant guess, for example 001).  If you can guess any 3 digit combo, it is 1/1000

Comment: If numbers can't start with $0$ there are $900$ possibilities, not $899$ ,aren't there?

Comment: Correct. Thanks for catching.